# Transition Between Two Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

Say I have two data sets, `data1` and `data2`

```
data1 = Range[1, 20, 1];
u = 0;
o = 6;
data2 = Table[Exp[-(x - u)^2/(2 o^2)], {x, 0, 20, 1}];
```

And they look something like

```
ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True]
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Is there any way I could animate a transition from data1 to data2, i.e. I'd like to see the data move into the new graph...like what can be seen [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a transition function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data1 = Range[0, 20, 1]/20;
u = 0;
o = 6;
data2 = Table[Exp[-(x - u)^2/(2 o^2)], {x, 0, 20, 1}];
data3[t_] :=  t data1 + (1 - t) data2;
Manipulate[ListPlot[data3[t], Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image]